# Multiply with negative integer just by shifting

Tags: c

I'm trying to find a way to multiply an integer value with negative value just with bit shifting.

Usually I do this by shifting with the power of 2 which is closest to my factor and just adding / subtracting the rest, e.g. `x * 7 = ((x << 3) - x)`

Let's say I'd want to calculate `x * -112`. The only way I can imagine is `-((x << 7) - (x << 4)`, so to calculate `x * 112` and negate it afterwards.

Is there a "prettier" way to do this?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the multiply functionality because of higher performance (I know, on today's computers you wouldn't notice it, but it's interesting though). Also I'm trying to get a better understanding of what's possible just with working on bits.

Comment: The compiler probably would turn the multiplication into shift-and-add instructions anyway.

Comment: @stex: You wouldn't notice the difference not because the computer is fast, but simply because the compiler will generate the same code for both multiplication and shifts-adds (assuming they are really equivalent). Actually, in most cases the compiler will be able to generate more efficient code for explicit multiplication than for your wild mix of shifts and adds. What you are trying do will not improve performance at all, and actually has a chance of making it worse.

Comment: Rebounding on AndreyT's comment, nowadays compilers go as far as reverse-engineering whatever obsolete optimization the programmer thought was appropriate, in order to re-optimize properly. See http://shape-of-code.coding-guidelines.com/2009/06/30/searching-for-the-source-line-implementing-3n1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The negative of a positive number in [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is done by negating all the bits and then adding 1 to the result. For example, to get -4 from 4 you would do:

`4 = 000...0100 in binary. ~4 = 111...1011. -4 = 111...1100.`

Same to reverse the sign.

So you could do this:

`(~((x << 7) - (x << 4))) + 1`.

Not necessarily prettier, but faster if we consider bitwise operations faster than arithmetic operations (especially multiplication) and ignore compiler optimizations.

Not that I'm saying you should do this, because you shouldn't. It's good to know about it though.

Answer (score 8):

Get the compiler to do it, then check the produced assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Computers internally represent negative integers in [two's compliment form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).  One of the nice properties of two's compliment arithmetic is that [multiply negative numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Multiplication) is just like multiplying positive numbers.  Hence, [find the two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Calculating_two.27s_complement) and use your normal approach.

Here's a simple example.  For ease of exposition, I'm going to using 8-bit integers and multiply by -15.

15 in hex is 0x0f.  The two's compliment of 0x0f is 0xf1.

Since these are 8-bit integers, all arithmetic is mod 0xff.  In particular, note that 0x100 * anything = 0.

```
x * 0xf1
= x * (0x100 - 0x10 + 0x01)
= -(x * 0x10) + x
= -(x << 4) + x
```